# How can i call my java program or jar in the apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have one main class in java and i want to call that class from nifi and use the logic in my nifi, could anyone please help me

```
public class TestDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstFile = "old.txt";
        String secondFile = "new.txt";
        try {
            Map<String, String> file1Data = readCSV(firstFile);// will read txt/csv file
            Map<String, String> file2Data = readCSV(secondFile);//will read txt/csv file
            compareAndMergeCSVs(file1Data, file2Data);//will compare both files based on my logs
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

now i want to call this class or jar file of this class from apachi nifi processor

Comment: please edit your question and show input/output parameters of your  class/method and expected behavior.

Comment: there are multiple options: you can use groovy script instead of java. or you can call custom class/jar from groovy. or you can start java as a separate process. or you can create custom processor using java. so provide as much details as possible, so we can recommend you something.

Comment: Hi @daggett thank you for the help, actually i have to compare two text files with each row first column(primary key) and made some delta out of these two files in to third files, so i tried to research if there is any nifi processors are already available to achieve this scenario and find no inbuilt processors are available, so i have created one standalone java program to achieve this and i have created a jar out of this and tried to read it from executescript and executestreamcommand processors but i am unable to read that jar, in executescript i want to write a groovy script to read my jar

Comment: please edit your question put all this information in there.

Comment: Hi @daggett i have provided my code, i need help to call that class from apachi nifi server, if we need to use groovy, could you please how can i write a groovy script to call this class

Answer (score 0):

The `main(String[] args)` where `args` contains file names to process is not efficient for nifi and for your use case.

here is the idea with `main(String[] args)` approach:

1. Use `MergeContent` to await for pair of files and zip those into one
2. use `ExecuteStreamCommand` to run jar

   `Command Path = java`

   `Command Arguments = -jar JarName`

   `Ignore STDIN = false`

   Your jar should read zip from `System.in`, take two files from zip, compare them, and print out result to `System.out`.

---

just to give you an idea how to use `ExecuteGroovyScript`

let's assume that in your jar there is a class with a method

`compareAndMergeCSVs( InputStream file1, InputStream file2, OutputStream result )`

in `Additional classpath` you can specify the path to your jar.

then use approximately the following code as `Script Body`:

```js
def ffList = session.get(2) //get not more then 2 files
if(!ffList || ffList.size()!=2)return

//create new flow file
def flowFile = session.create()
flowFile.write{outStream->
  def myObj = new mypackage.MyClass()
  // assume your method accepts 3 parameters:
  // 1st InputStream, 2nt InputStream, and OutputStream to write a result
  myObj.compareAndMergeCSVs( ffList[0].read(), ffList[1].read(), outStream )
}
flowFile.filename = "new-file-name"

// drop old flowfiles
ffList[0].remove()  //remove old flowfile
ffList[1].remove()  //remove old flowfile

// transfer new flowfile to success
REL_SUCCESS << flowFile
```

> Note: `session.get(2)` will take first two files from incoming queue and it's possible that you want to group pairs differently.

If you need to select a pair of flowfiles then use the `MergeContent` processor with zipping 2 files into one zip and then in your code unzip them.

Comment: sure thank you, will try and let you know if i have any issues

Comment: If i use mergecontent and then zip and then read it from my java code, actually after merge content processor i will be having only one file with merging of the two files data right then how can i compare those files in my java method, could you please help me to explain little bit deeper please. I mean how do i know from the merging file data which data if from file A and which data is from file B

Comment: you should have 2 files in zip. you can read then from code and compare. what do you mean by A and B? filename? creation datetime?